# what size to upload an image for image buttons?

Tags: android, image, button, resolution, imagebutton

When trying to upload an image for different resolutions and screen sizes what size should I upload the image to correctly fit as an Image button?

Right now I have image buttons used for xhdpi screens but when I switch to a screen with just hdpi the layout seems to go off the screen. I have the image buttons set as 100dp for width and height and when i try to wrap content for both of those the image buttons become really enlarged so I assumed that I uploaded them the wrong size.

Comment: Where would you upload them to?

Comment: with upload I guess he means importing into Android Studio?

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I meant importing them into Android Studio to use as an image button.